# MySQL Loop Through Each Row

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, division & template, in a MySQL database.

```
division
    - DivisionID
    - DivisionName

template
    - TemplateID
    - TemplateName
```

Here is an example of my current data set.

```
division
    - 1, Marketing
    - 2, Commerce
    - 3, Infrastructure


template
    - 1, Awareness
    - 2, AAR Summary
    - 3, Release Acceptance
```

I'm looking for a result set of:

```
Marketing Awareness
Marketing AAR Summary
Marketing Release Acceptance
Commerce Awareness
Commerce AAR Summary
Commerce Release Acceptance
Infrastructure Awareness
Infrastructure AAR Summary
Infrastructure Release Acceptance
```

Everything else I've seen that is similar to this is using a PHP or other script to accomplish. How would I achieve something like this using pure MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For different columns

```
select DivisionName, TemplateName from division join tmplate;
```

If you want each row as a single column string

```
select concat(DivisionName,' ', TemplateName) from division join tmplate;
```

Comment: SELECT DivisionName, TemplateName FROM division JOIN template ORDER BY DivisionName; Thanks!!!